# Can you make non-fist unarmed attacks?

Tags: unarmed-combat, pathfinder-2e

The [section for Unarmed Strikes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=223) says you can make attacks with your fists, or other body parts, however the Equipment section only lists "[Fist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=1)" as an available Unarmed attack. Does this mean that without some extra feat or ability, you cannot make kicks, elbows, or other unarmed attacks?  Alternatively, if you can make these attacks by default, what are their stats? Is it the same as those for the "Fist"?

Answer (score 11):

The section you linked explains it:

> Unarmed Attacks lists the statistics for an unarmed attack with a fist, though **you’ll usually use the same statistics for attacks made with any other parts of your body**.

So kicks, headbutts and so forth use the Fist stats unless you have a feature which gives a different Unarmed attack.

Comment: As an addendum (may or may not be worth including): this is because things got confusing in 1e, where Fist was instead Unarmed Strike, which is different from an Unarmed Attack (unarmed strike is an unarmed attack, but there are unarmed attacks which aren't unarmed strike, like a normal gauntlet-as-a-weapon attack). Separating the two concepts into Fist (the weapon) and Unarmed (the Trait) helps to resolve those issues, and a short description helps clarify that Fist can be for kicks or headbutts or whatever as well.